# Java server Python client

Tags: java, python, process

I have a java server python client application, which python sends strings to java

I'm using `ProcessBuilder` and `Process` to launch the python client code from java automatically, the code works as expected, but after few minutes the client stops sending data to server. 
When i run the python code manually (not from the java process and process builder) it works like a charm and sends data without ending as expected. 
i can't determine where is the problem, but everything alone works fine.
Here is my java code to start the process:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb;
 Process p = null;
  try {

            pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","test.py");
            pb.directory(new File("D:\\PythonCodes\\"));
            p = pb.start();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

any help?

Comment: Are you calling `p.waitFor();` anywhere?

Comment: no, i just started it